# Python Join List Elements

Tags: list, python-3.x

Given the following lists:

```
A=['a','b','c']
B=[1,2]
```

I'd like to join the values such that each element of B is joined to each of A like this:

```
['a1','a2','b1','b2','c1','c2']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 1-liner works:

```
[x+str(y) for x in A for y in B]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A=['a','b','c']
B=[1,2]

C = []
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        C.append( str(a) + str(b) )
print(C)
```

Result:

```
['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2']
```